# How determine flow rate of air into a sealed vessel with increasing pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, flow, air

I am able to measure a target pressure inside the vessel or rate of increasing pressure, temperature and know th volume of the vessel (1000L). I would like to determine flow rate of air from a compressor into the vessel. The air pressure from the compressor is 6000 mbar. If I flow air into this vessel until I reach 1000mbar can I use pv=nrt to determine flow rate of air entering the vessel?

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is your process adiabatic, isothermal, or other?  This process requires PV work, and the heat transfer conditions of the process are important.

Comment: has a flow meter but needs calibration